# Std_logic_vector adding function

Tags: function, vhdl

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity unu is
port(a,b:std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    q:out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
   );
end unu;

architecture Behavioral of unu is

function max (op1, op2 : INTEGER) return INTEGER is
    begin
        if op1 > op2 then
           return op1;
        else
           return op2;
        end if;
    end max;

function "+"( A,B:std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
constant size1: INTEGER := a'LENGTH;
constant size2: INTEGER := b'LENGTH;
constant size:integer :=max(size1,size2)+1;
variable result:std_logic_vector(size downto 0);
begin
result:=std_logic_vector(unsigned(A)+unsigned(B));
return result;
end "+";

begin
q<=a+b;  --line 28

end Behavioral;
```

I receive this error

ERROR:HDLCompiler:410 -Line 28: Expression has 2 elements ; expected 4

I'm trying to make a function that adds two std_logic_vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a requirement in assignment that there is an element on the right hand side for every element on the left hand side.  Your left hand side signal q has 3 elements.  The expression on the right hand side has 4 (max length of A and B,plus 1, plus identity (size downto 0).

The failure is actually in assigning the std_logic_vector conversion of the unsigned "+" operator result to result in the function, which you have made length 4:

```
constant size:integer :=max(size1,size2)+1;
variable result:std_logic_vector(size downto 0);
```

If you want a "+" operator that adds std_logic_vector values as unsigned  and increases the length by one try:

```
architecture Behavioral of unu is

    -- function max (op1, op2 : INTEGER) return INTEGER is
    --     begin
    --         if op1 > op2 then
    --            return op1;
    --         else
    --            return op2;
    --         end if;
    --     end max;

    function "+"( A,B:std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    -- constant size1: INTEGER := a'LENGTH;
    -- constant size2: INTEGER := b'LENGTH;
    -- constant size:integer :=max(size1,size2)+1;
    -- variable result:std_logic_vector(size downto 0);
    begin
    -- result:=std_logic_vector(unsigned(A)+unsigned(B));
    -- return result;
    return std_logic_vector('0' & unsigned(A)+unsigned(B));
    end "+";

begin
    q<=a+b;  --line 28

end Behavioral;
```

You could achieve the same result by:

```
    return std_logic_vector(unsigned(A)+unsigned(B));
```

And resizing one of the operands or the result assigned to q:

```
    q <= ('0' & a) + b;
```

OR

```
    q <= a + ('0' & b);
```

OR

```
    q <= '0' & (a + b);
```

Sign extending only makes sense for signed addition. Operand padding gives the normal arithmetic meaning for the result.

The function declaration for unsigned "+" in package numeric_std:

```
function "+" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
-- Result subtype: UNSIGNED(MAX(L'LENGTH, R'LENGTH)-1 downto 0).
-- Result: Adds two UNSIGNED vectors that may be of different lengths.
```

Shows the length of the result is adjusted for the maximum of the length of the Left or Right argument already.